# Saving derived classes to a single table in EF Core with runtime loading support

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have some custom classes, such as `BarcodeDevice` and `LightDevice`, which are derived from a base class called `Device`. I have the following requirements:

1. Save all the custom classes into one table, the `Device` table.
2. Each custom class may contain different properties depending on the functionality of the class (device).
3. Some custom classes are already loaded together with the project, while others will be created later on and loaded in some way, for example by uploading a `Dll` file. Therefore, once the project goes live, the code cannot be changed.
4. The individual custom classes can be retrieved by loading the `Device` object from the database using `DbContext`.

I am currently using `Discriminator` and it works, but it only runs once, and thus does not support adding custom classes at runtime. How can I solve this issue?

`DbContext`:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Configure device type for each type.
        modelBuilder.Entity<BarcodeDevice>()
            .HasDiscriminator(p => p.Type)
            .HasValue(nameof(BarcodeDevice));
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<LightDevice>()
            .HasDiscriminator(p => p.Type)
            .HasValue(nameof(LightDevice));
    }
}
```

Custom Class:

```cs
public class BarcodeDevice : Device
{
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    
    private SerialPort serial { get; set; }
    private string barcodeValue { get; set;}
    
    // other properties
}
```

Service:

```cs
public class DeviceService : IDeviceService
{
    // Some variables
    
    public DeviceService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        var dbContext = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()
            .ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        Devices = dbContext.Devices.ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < Devices.Count; i++)
        {
            Devices[i].StartInstance();
            Devices[i].OnMessageSend += Device_OnMessageSend;
        }

        _mqttClient = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()
            .ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IResolverMqttClient>();

        _mqttClient.OnMqttMessageReceived += MqttClient_OnMqttMessageReceived;
    }
    
    // some methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options.

1. Push back on 3).  Do you *really* need that?
2. don't use EF,

or

3. have only a JSON column mapped to store the varying attributes of each device type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need a solution to maintain the functionality of each custom class when introducing new components through a DLL file. Can you provide more information or alternative approaches to effectively handle this situation?

Comment: Can you update the database schema when introducing new classes?  That’s the normal approach.

Comment: I would like to not update the database schema. When I run the project, I can install new components (classes) through DLL.  Anyone in my team can also develop new components for IoT devices and upload to the app. Updating database schema for every new component is not suitable.